# Canvas overlaying disappearing after enlarge twice on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am experiencing a weird bug that I do not know how to fix. When I click a button on my website called "Enlarge" it starts an overlay and inside there is a canvas that loads a protein structure. But when I click the close button and try to enlarge it again it loads up nothing and I can't seem to figure out why.

**Example HTML**

```
<!-- Expanded Canvas-->
                    <div id= "myNav" class ="overlay">
                            <a href="javascript:void[0]" class = "closebtn" onClick="closeNav()">X</a>
                            <div class = "overlay-content">
                                <div class = "fixed">
                                </div>
                                <div id = "viewer2">
                                        <canvas id = "expandedCanvas"></canvas>     
                                </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
<a  id = "expandImage" style = "cursor:pointer">[Enlarge]</a>
<script>

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";    
        document.getElementById("sequence-label").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("picked-atom-name").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("proteinAlbum").style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

**The JS**

```
function expandImage() {

expandImageButton = true;

    //Start off as default for both the buttons not showing 
show("antibodyOn", false);
show("antibodyOff", false);

//Reset the width 
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
viewer.requestRedraw();

viewer = pv.Viewer(document.getElementById('viewer2'), { 
    antialias : true, fog : true,
    outline : true, quality : 'high', style : 'phong',
    selectionColor : 'white', transparency : 'screendoor', 
    background : '#111215', animateTime: 500, doubleClick : null,

});

//Fit to the nav bar
viewer.fitParent();

this.value = "";
this.blur();

// Same principle as the loadFromPdb
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
XHR.open("GET", urlPdb, true);
XHR.send();
XHR.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (XHR.readyState === 4) {
        if (XHR.status === 200 || XHR.status === 0) {
         staticProteinLabel = XHR.responseText.slice(0, XHR.responseText.indexOf("\n")).substr(62, 4).trim();
         var canvasStaticLabel = document.getElementById('static-label');
         canvasStaticLabel.textContent = staticProteinLabel;
         typeOfProtein = XHR.responseText.slice(0, XHR.responseText.indexOf("\n")).substr(10, 26).trim();
         var result = XHR.responseText;
         var allLines = result.split("\n");
         var lineTwo = String(allLines[1]);
         alert(lineTwo);
         var antibodyText = "ANTIBODY";
            if (typeOfProtein === "COMPLEX (ANTIBODY-ANTIGEN)") {
                isAntibody = true;
                anitbodyOn();
                }
            else if (lineTwo.indexOf(antibodyText) ) {
                isAntibody = true;
                antibodyOn();
            }
          }
        }
    }

io.fetchPdb(urlPdb, function(s) {
  structure = s;
  mol.assignHelixSheet(structure);
  cartoon();
  viewer.autoZoom();
  });

}
```

So I was wondering if it was just the problem with the changing of the width and it can't load up the viewer again and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: In **closeNav()** some elements are being hidden, but I only see one of them unhidden in **expandImage()**

Comment: Oh so there is some HTML I omitted from the example above otherwise it would look like a block of code. Those elements are triggered by a nav bar with user options. and they stick on the overlay. After the user closes them I made them disappear. When the user reopens it, he/she has the option of choosing those elements again.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out. The data inside of the canvas needs to be destroyed, so I wrote a little function to erase the data and clear the canvas so it can reload again.